# Draw vertices with thread in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using glut library with `opengl` and draw circle with it. Circle is draw successfully on frame but what i want compile these circle vertices in a thread. For example i put in circle loop, Every vertex draw after `2seconds` is completed than on run time it appear that vertex on frame which seconds are passed. I am using `sleep()` function but doesn't work with it.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
using namespace std;

void init(void) {


    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

}



void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case '\x1B':
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        break;
    }
}

void drawCircle(float pointX, float pointY, float Radius, int segment)
{




    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

    for (int i = 0; i < segment; i++)
    {
        float thetha= i * (2.0f * (float)M_PI / segment);
        float x = Radius * cos(thetha);
        float y = Radius * sin(thetha);
        Sleep(2000);
        glVertex2f(x + pointX, y + pointY);




    }
    glEnd();
}

void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    drawCircle(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.80f, 360);
    glFlush();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(590, 590);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,50);
    glutCreateWindow("Frame");
    init();
    glutKeyboardFunc(&keyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(&display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to draw a circle then wait 2 seconds then draw again.  If that is what you want, you have the sleep in the wrong place.  By having the sleep inside the segment for loop you are sleeping between each vertex point, but if you want to sleep between successive draws of the circle, move the sleep to after the glEnd() call or into your main display method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to animate the drawing of the circle. Draw commands in OpenGL are not issued immediately - you need to draw, and then present the results to the window. So, having a `sleep` within a drawing function will delay the presentation. With the code that you've posted, you're sleeping for 2 seconds each iteration of the loop within `drawCircle`. Since you're passing in `segment=360`, it will take about 12 minutes to render your circle (and your application will appear to hang during this time). Likely, you should draw frames with the circle in one state for 2 seconds, and then draw the next state.

To achieve this, you should remove the `sleep`, and have a timer within your `display` function, which increases the `segment` parameter as time passes. Eg:

```
#include <ctime>
// ...
void display()
{
    static clock_t startTime = clock(); // NOTE: evaluated only once
    clock_t currentTime = clock();
    float timeLength = 2.0f * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    float circlePercentage = (currentTime - startTime) / timeLength;        
    circlePercentage = circlePercentage >= 1.0f ? 1.0f : circlePercentage; //clamp
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    drawCircle(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.80f, static_cast<int>(circlePercentage * 360));
    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: currentTime,startTime,timeLength how to initialize these variables and these are giving red underline

Comment: You could initialize them with ctime, for example.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/

Comment: updated, clocks is a better fit for timing, as the resolution is higher - however, it's not 'true' wallclock time, but probably good enough for your purposes.

Comment: but your code draw circle on frame when the time is passed.but is there a way,When the frame is show than we can see each vertex draw immediately and make a full circle

Comment: if you want to draw the full circle immediately, just set `circlePercentage = 1.0f`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103755/discussion-between-john-doe-and-muertoexcobito).